# How do I export a reference to the database connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm connecting to a database in my main.js using the following code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

MongoClient.connect(process.env.PROD_MONGODB, function(err, database) {
    if(err) { return console.dir(err); }

    db = database;
});
```

And later in the file I can do this:

```
db.collection('players').update({id: player.id}, {$set: {x: player.x, y: player.y}}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(err, result);
});
```

Now I want to make a similar database update in another file but can't figure out how to export the connection.

I've tried *exports.db = db* and requiring it with *var db = require('./main').db* but it ends up undefined in the other file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical problem with trying to use the result of an asynchronous operation before it is complete.

Instead of trying to export the `db` connection and keep it open indefinitely, export a function that creates a connection and allows you to use it:

```
exports.useDb = function (f) {
    MongoClient.connect(process.env.PROD_MONGODB, function(err, database) {
        try {
            f(err, database);
        } finally {
            database.close();
        }
    });
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var useDb = require('./main').useDb;

useDb(function (err, db) {
    db.collection('players').update({id: player.id}, {$set: {x: player.x, y: player.y}}, function(err, result) {
        console.log(err, result);
    });
});
```